# Ошибка при вызове метода объекта с использованием?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет и извиняюсь за кривую формулировку. Если вызывать метод таким образом

```
let user = {
  name: "Джон",
  hi() { console.log((this.name)) },
  bye() { console.log('Bye') }
};


(user.name === "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye)(); // Ошибка!
```

А если вызвать так, то все работает

```
let user = {
  name: "Джон",
  hi() { console.log((this.name)) },
  bye() { console.log('Bye') }
};

(user.hi)() // Джон
```

Хотя и там и там есть скобки вокруг. Недавно начал учить JS помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: разница в том, что в первом случае идет вычисление выражения, а во втором, обращение к полю

Comment: добавил еще один дубликат, с полной копией твоего вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

В JavaScript функция знает какому объекту равен `this`, только если она вызвана на этом объекте, например:

```js
user.hi();
```

Если функция была передана как callback, или сохранена в переменную, или после доступа к ней через объект было сделано что-то еще кроме вызова, то `this` не привязывается. В этом случае можно явно передать `this` с помощью `.apply()`:

```js
const fn = user.name === "Джон" ? user.hi : user.bye;
fn.apply(user);
```